# How to find the next match with re-builder?

Tags: regular-expressions

I built a complicated regular expression with re-builder and see that it works with the matches I want. How can I find all the matches, as I would with `C-s` in `isearch-forward`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have a look into the `Re-Builder` menu. There you find the menu item `Go to next match` bound to <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd>.

Comment: This is embarrassing. I'm so used to programming that I missed the extra menu bar item `Re-Builder` in the point-and-click GUI.

Comment: Alternatively, the standard `C-h m` will show you the mode bindings.